# How to place text boxes in Python Turtle?

Tags: python

I'm making a mock OS in python Turtle, and I want to make a username and password prompt. Thing is, I don't want a turtle text window, I want just the type box. and I want to be able to place it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you _have_ to use turtles? It's a toy interface not suitable (and not intended) for any serious development.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use turtle? 
Turtle was meant to help you get used to the language before you can build any full-fledged applications. This means it is extremely limited in what it can do.

If you are looking to build a GUI application then I recommend you check out [TKinter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm)

I should also point out that you will not be able to build an OS using just python as python is a high-level language. This means it cannot directly interact the hardware.

However, you could write the low-level memory management using C and assembly language and write the rest of your high-level code in python.